# PHP module installed but does not appear in phpinfo()

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php5, php

Im tying to install php5-ffmpeg module on my ubuntu server. I've typed:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-ffmpeg
```

Everything was installed and web server was reloaded. Now, the fallowing line is added to `Additional .ini files parsed` in phpinfo(): `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ffmpeg.ini`

However, no more info about `ffmpeg` module is not present in phpinfo() and ffmpeg functions do not work in scripts. Here's `ffmpeg.ini` file contents:

```
; configuration for the ffmpeg-php module

extension=ffmpeg.so

; Turn ffmpeg warnings into PHP warnings
;ffmpeg.show_warnings=0

; Persistent movies
;ffmpeg.allow_persistent=0
```

PHPInfo screenshot: http://i050.radikal.ru/1011/41/021944f4f1c4.png

Apache error log shows:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ffmpeg.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

It is said there `PHP Extension: 20090626`

I have two directories in `/usr/lib/php5`:

```
20060613+lfs/
    ffmpeg.so
20090626+lfs/
    curl.so    gd.so      mysql.so      pdo.so
    mysqli.so  pdo_mysql.so  suhosin.so
```

I've tried copying `ffmpeg.so` to `20090626+lfs` directory, but in this case Apache error log shows:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ffmpeg: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20060613\nPHP    compiled with module API=20090626\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ffmpeg: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20060613\nPHP    compiled with module API=20090626\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas why PHP ffmpeg module does not work in this case?

Ubuntu server 9.04,
PHP 5.3.1-4,
Apache 2

Comment: What do your startup errors say? Web server error log?

Comment: Try to restart apache2 process!

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, sorry, I've edited the question with details from error.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've installed a copy of the ffmpeg extension that was built against a different version of PHP. You'll need to either find one built against the correct version, or build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Clearly this is the issue. I don't know how to compile the module, but that's another question.